A question about sum with reciprocal quartic

Evaluate
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+8}{n^{4}+4}
$$

According to WolframAlpha it is $\pi\coth(\pi) - \dfrac{5}{8}$
My attempt:
I tried to separate $\dfrac{n}{n^{4}+4}$ and $\dfrac{8}{n^{4}+4}$. Now the first term is $\dfrac{3}{8}$ since
$$
n^4 + 4 = \bigl((n+1)^2 + 1\bigr)\bigl((n-1)^2 + 1)\bigr).
$$
With partial fraction decomposition, this turns into a simple telescoping sum.
However I have no idea what to do with the second term. Only thing I can think of is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}
$$
since it is similar looking, but I could not find a way to make use of it.
I'll be glad for any help. Thanks in advance.

See if you can utilize the identity $\pi\coth(\pi x) = \frac1{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2 + n^2}$.

@user43208 Thanks,  one way I can think of to use the identity you just gave, for $x=1$ we have
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2 + 1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8}{n^4 + 4} = \pi \coth(\pi)-1$
(since we know the answer beforehand). But unfortunately, I don't know how to prove this two sums are equal.

Partial fraction decomposition yields
\begin{align}
\frac{8}{n^4+4} 
&= \frac{1+i}{2(n + 1 + i)} + \frac{1-i}{2(n + 1 - i)} - \frac{1-i}{2(n - 1 + i)} - \frac{1+i}{2(n - 1 - i)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n + 1 + i} + \frac{1}{n + 1 - i} - \frac{1}{n - 1 + i} - \frac{1}{n - 1 - i}\right) \\&+ \left(\frac{i}{2(n + 1 + i)} - \frac{i}{2(n + 1 - i)}\right) + \left(\frac{i}{2(n - 1 + i)} - \frac{i}{2(n - 1 - i)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n + 1 + i} + \frac{1}{n + 1 - i} - \frac{1}{n - 1 + i} - \frac{1}{n - 1 - i}\right) \\&+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1} + \frac{1}{(n-1)^2+1}.
\end{align}
The first grouping telescopes to $-1/2$, and the rest sums to
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1} + \frac{1}{(n-1)^2+1}\right)
&= \frac{1}{0^2+1} + \frac{1}{1^2+1} + 2\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1},
\end{align}
so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{8}{n^4+4} = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1},$$
which is known to be $\pi \coth \pi - 1$.

Too long for a comment
$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac8{n^4+4}=-1+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac4{n^4+4}=-1+4S(a=\sqrt2)$$
where we denote
$$S(a)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{n^4+a^4}$$
A standart way of evaluation such sums is the integration in the complex plane along a big circle of the radius $R\to\infty$ (contour $C$)
$$\oint_C\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{z^4+a^4}dz=2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{z^4+a^4}\right)\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,R\to\infty$$
Simple poles at $z=0;\pm1;\pm2...$ give us $S(a)$; we also have poles in the points $z=e^{\pm\frac{\pi i}4}a;\,e^{\pm\frac{3\pi i}4}a$
Therefore,
$$S(a)+\underset{z=e^{\pm\frac{\pi i}4}a;\,e^{\pm\frac{3\pi i}4}a}{\operatorname{Res}}\left(\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{z^4+a^4}\right)=0$$
In our case $a=\sqrt2$, what gives considerable simplification. Using $\,\cot\big(\pi(\pm1+i)\big)=\cot (\pi i)=-i\coth\pi$
$$S(\sqrt2)+\underset{z=1\pm i;\,-1\pm i}{\operatorname{Res}}\left(\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{(z-(1+i))(z-(1-i))(z-(-1+i))(z-(-1-i))}\right)=0$$
$$S(\sqrt2)=\frac\pi 8\coth\pi\cdot2\cdot\frac{1-i+1-i}{1-i^2}=\frac\pi4\coth\pi$$
$$\boxed{\,\,S_2=-1+\pi\coth\pi\,\,}$$
